# Why can't I create an "In-App Purchase Content" target in XCode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am adding an in-app purchase to my iOS application that unlocks a feature to render images at a higher resolution. To achieve this, I would like to leverage Apple's Content Hosting feature for in-app purchases.

I found a number of guides on the topic (1), and all indicate the need to create a separate project or target in XCode of type "In-App Purchase Content". However, I am not seeing that as an option when creating a new project or target in XCode.

Here is the "In-App Purchase Content" option I would expect to see:

[image: expected xcode project template]

Here are the only options I see in XCode under the Multiplatform & Other tabs, it is not present in any of the other tabs either:

[image: actual xcode project template]

[image]

In App Store Connect, the app is configured with the in-app purchase, Content Hosting is turned on, and I can make a test purchase for that non-consumable product (without the content download). I also am working with the latest version of XCode.

When searching the web, I can't find any indication why that option may be missing for me in XCode. Does anyone see a step I might be missing to enable this in XCode?

---

(1) Some of the guides I am referencing:

- [Apple: Unlocking Purchased Content](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/unlocking_purchased_content)
- [Techotopia: Configuring and Creating App Store Hosted Content for iOS 11 In-App Purchases](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_and_Creating_App_Store_Hosted_Content_for_iOS_8_In-App_Purchases)
- [Kitefaster: How to use Content Hosting for In-App Purchase Content](https://kitefaster.com/2017/06/14/use-content-hosting-app-purchase-content/)

Comment: It should be under the "Other" tab

Comment: A good suggestion, but it is not present in any of the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this may have been removed in Xcode 13.3, per the following release note:

> Building and uploading nonconsumable in-app purchase content for Apple to host is no longer supported. Existing content that’s hosted by Apple isn’t affected. To enable smaller app bundles, faster downloads, and richer app content, use on-demand resources to host your content on the App Store separately from the app bundle. For details, see On-Demand Resources Essentials. (84121695)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode-Release-Notes/xcode-13_3-release-notes